# Disable Stylus Gestures for WinForm

Tags: winforms, stylus-pen

I need to disable all stylus gestures for a winform. I want the stylus to function normally (i.e. basically as a mouse substitute) but the stylus gestures are majorly in the way.
Ideally, the gestures would only be disabled for a specific form, but application wide is also acceptable.

Since my app is full screen I could even settle for disabling stylus gestures system wide but would need to restore the original state when the app exits.

So far, what I have is:
I catch the WM_TABLET_FLICK message in the WndProc and return with FLICK_WM_HANDLED_MASK, indicating the no further action is required.

That works in the sense that the flick is ignored. HOWEVER, I also loose all stylus movement that is part of the flick. It seems to me that I need to disable the flicks on a deeper level, such that the system doesn't even bother trying to recognize any flicks to begin with.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

catch WM_TABLET_QUERYSYSTEMGESTURESTATUS in WndProc and return TABLET_DISABLE_FLICKS.

that disables even the detection of flicks, i.e. no stylus movement gets lost.

further "info":
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb969148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)